# Edit ID markup in source

Tags: asp.net

I recently install VS on a new machine. I imported a project that I was working on to this new machine. The same code is running differently. Both machine are running VS2010 Premium.

This is the markup on new machine

```
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkReview" class="g10pn" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lnkReview','')">REVIEWS</a>
```

This is markup on old machine

```
<a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkReview" class="g10pn" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lnkReview','')">REVIEWS</a>
```

This causes a problem when I build my jquery selectors. Also of note even after I load page and do post backs the old machines code never adds the 'ct100' to the a tag id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running .NET 4, you can [influence the ClientID](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=492) that is automatically generated, using the ClientIDMode.